# Why does samba with netbios aliases only load one of the configurations?

Tags: linux, samba, opensuse, alias, netbios

I'm running an OpenSuSE 11.3 box with samba v3.5.4.  I've set up my `smb.conf` as follows:

```
[global]
        netbios aliases = jean-pc2 storage
        include = /etc/samba/smb.conf.%L
```

Then I have two other config files, `smb.conf.jean-pc2` and `smb.conf.storage`

`smb.conf.jean-pc`

```
[global]
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
        security = SHARE
        guest account = smbguest
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192

[production]
        path = /data/shared/jean-pc
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes

[remmert]
        path = /data/shared/jean-pc/remmert
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes
```

`smb.conf.storage`

```
[global]
        socket options = TCP_NODELAY IPTOS_LOWDELAY SO_KEEPALIVE SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
        security = share
        guest account = smbguest
        workgroup = WORKGROUP
[Data]
        path = /data/shared
        browseable = yes
        read only = no
        guest ok = yes

[websites]
        comment = Apache published directory
        path = /srv/www/htdocs
        read only = No
        browseable = yes
        guest ok = yes
```

The problem I'm having is that only the `storage` file is being used.  Both aliases appear in the computers list in windows, but when I open `jean-pc`, it has the `data` and `websites` shares, instead of the expected `production` and `remmert` shares.

Regardless of the order in which I list the aliases, only the shares from the `storage` configuration are being used.

Why is Samba behaving like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because when samba listens on port 445 (the new default) it does not get NetBIOS information from the client.

Setting it to listen on port 139 only (using `smb ports = 139`) causes it to fallback to the older protocol in which the NetBIOS information is transmitted, which makes it work as expected.

Comment: you saved my day!!